# Answer verification regarding fundamental period.

Tags: periodic-functions

**Question:** $x(t)= -2 + 5cos(50\pi t +\frac{\pi}{3}) + 2sin(120\pi t)$, where t is in seconds. Find the fundamental period for this signal. What is its frequency in Hertz and in radians per second?

**My attempt:** $$T_1 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}=\frac{2\pi}{50\pi}=1/25$$
$$T_2 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}=\frac{2\pi}{120\pi}=1/60$$

LCM of $T_1 \ \& \ T_2$ is $\frac{1}{5}$, hence:$$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$\omega=10\pi$$

Frequency in rps would be $10\pi=31.4159$
and the frequency in Hertz is $5$.

My hesitation here is how does the initial **$-2$** term make a difference if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-2$ as a constant addition makes no difference – it merely translates the graph, which does not change the period if it exists.

Comment: So my fundamental period is correct, right?

Comment: @AhsonYousef Yes.